# Converting to Guid but Receive cannot convert to int error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, string, controller, guid

I am trying to use a linq statement to pull a userName out of my database for a string.  However I keep getting an error.

This is the error I am getting:

> Cannot implicitly convert 'string' to 'int'

which is quite odd because I am trying to convert it to a Guid, not an int.

here is the code:

```
string ticketChange = "The following change(s) have been made by " + db.Users.Where(u => u.UserId == new Guid["LoggedUserID"]).First().FullName + Environment.NewLine;
```

I am receiving the error on the "loggedUserID" which currently is a string.

Here is the code where I define LoggedUserID when the user logs in. (I know this is not the best way to perform this, which I will change in the future but I need to get this fixed soon).  It pulls the userID which is a quid out of the database and saves it as a string.

```
Session["LoggedUserID"] = v.UserId.ToString();
```

I have also tried:

```
Guid.NewGuid(["LoggedUserID"])
```

but there is no overload method for NewGuid that takes any arguments.

u.UserID is a Guid.  So how do I convert the string to a Guid in this case for it to work?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish here. What is "LoggedUserId" supposed to be?

The error is related to `new Guid["LoggedUserId"]`. A `Guid` is not a dictionary, so I'm not sure why you think you can index it or that it would have a key named "LoggedUserId" implicitly, even if you could. You *could* pass something to the constructor: `new Guid(...)`, however, the passed value must be something that can be converted to a `Guid`, which "LoggedUserId" is not.

Comment: Hi Chris. I updated my question to include what the LoggedUserID is

Comment: Then, you need to do something like `new Guid(Session["LoggedUserID"])`. However, that's *very* fragile, so you really should wrap that in a try-catch block and handle the scenario where the session variable is empty or non-standard  for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

With Chris's help this is what ended up working:

```
Guid g = Guid.Parse(Session["LoggedUserID"] as string);

string ticketChange = "The following change(s) have been made by "  + db.Users.Where(u => u.UserId == g).First().FullName + Environment.NewLine;
```